# How to return different type of objects overloading sum function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, object, sum, overloading

I have a class `Data` and I want to overload the `__add__` function and get different type of objects based on the type of the objects I sum.

### Toy example code

The `Data` class is as follows:

```
class Data(object):

    def __str__(self):
        s = "Data type " + self.type + ": " + self.tag
        return s

    def __init__(self, tag=""):
        self.type = ""
        self.tag = tag
        self.df = pd.Series()

    def createRandomData(self, amountData=10, sizeData=100):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,sizeData,size=(amountData, 1)))[0]

    def __add__(self, other):
        data = Data()
        data = Data(self.tag + "+" + other.tag)
        data.df = self.df + other.df
        return data
```

I also have two different objects `DataTypeA` and `DataTypeB` which inherit from `Data`.

```
class DataTypeA(Data):

    def __init__(self, tag=""):
        Data.__init__(self, tag)
        self.type = "A"

class DataTypeB(Data):

    def __init__(self, tag=""):
        Data.__init__(self, tag)
        self.type = "B"
```

### Expected result

So I would like to ensure that when I sum two objects from same type of Data (e.g.: `DataTypeA`+ `DataTypeA`) the result is also of that type of Data. But when two objects are of different types (e.g.: `DataTypeA`+ `DataTypeB`) the result should be a `Data` object.

The result for the sum should be the sum of the Series in `df` and the tag should be the tag of the first object concatenated with "+" and finally the second tag.

### Example

By now if I run following code:

```
a = DataTypeA("data1")
a.createRandomData()
b = DataTypeB("data2")
b.createRandomData()

a2 = a+a
b2 = b+b
c = a+b

print a
print b
print a2
print b2
print c
```

I get as result:

```
>>> 
Data type A: data1
Data type B: data2
Data type : data1+data1
Data type : data2+data2
Data type : data1+data2
```

But `a2` (data1+data1) should be of type `DataTypeA` instead `Data`, and `b2` (data2+data2) should be of type `DataTypeB` instead of `Data`.

### Question

How to rewrite this code to achieve this and which would be the best way? Should I rewrite the `__add__` method for `Data` object or overload `__add__` method for `DataTypeA` and `DataTypeB` instead?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to overload the `Data` object `__add__` method as follows:

```
class Data(object):

    def __str__(self):
        s = "Data type " + self.type + ": " + self.tag
        return s

    def __init__(self, tag=""):
        self.type = ""
        self.tag = tag
        self.df = pd.Series()

    def createRandomData(self, amountData=10, sizeData=100):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,sizeData,size=(amountData, 1)))[0]

    def __add__(self, other):
        data = Data()
        if type(self) == type(other):
            if type(self) == DataTypeA:
                data = DataTypeA(self.tag + "+" + other.tag)
                data.df = self.df + other.df
            elif type(self) == DataTypeB:
                data = DataTypeB(self.tag + "+" + other.tag)
                data.df = self.df + other.df
        else:
            data = Data(self.tag + "+" + other.tag)
            data.df = self.df + other.df
        return data
```

The rest of the code would remain the same.

So if you run the same example code mentioned in the question the output would be:

```
>>> 
Data type A: data1
Data type B: data2
Data type A: data1+data1
Data type B: data2+data2
Data type : data1+data2
```